# Notation for convex combinations

Tags: reference-request, notation, convex-analysis

In my work I often need to use convex combinations. Of course I can write $(1-\theta)a+\theta b$ for the convex combination between $a$ and $b$ to the parameter $\theta$. However I had the idea to introduce a shorthand notation for this. Despite the hope that it maybe becomes a bit shorter, another reason is to emphasize that an expression is a convex combination and to highlight what belongs to the points and what to the parameter, what in more complicated expressions is sometimes useful.

Hence my question: Are you aware of works in which something similar was introduces, what was the notation there, or do you have yourself suggestions for a good notation?

Comment: I've never seen notation for this, but i doubt it would be significantly shorter and it would be likely significantly less clear than writing it out.

Answer (score 1):

For [interpolation spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#Complex_interpolation), which also involve a parameter $\theta\in (0,1)$, there is a standard notation
$(X_0, X_1)_\theta$. 
So you could follow that approach and write $(a,b)_\theta$. If the parentheses could be mistaken for something else, $[a,b]_\theta$ may be a better alternative.  It is also more suggestive because $[a,b]$ usually means the line segment from $a$ to $b$, which the function $\theta\mapsto [a,b]_\theta$ parameterizes.

Another sort of notation is found in literature on metric spaces with "geodesic bicombing" such as [Descombes & Lang](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5051.pdf) (search for "geodesic bicombing" to find more). The convex combinations serve as the canonical example of such bicombing. The notation I see used for these is $\sigma_{a b}(\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The notation coming from interpolation spaces is a very nice idea, I will try this out. However since the context in which I want to use it heavily uses abstract interpolation theory, I cannot say yet whether it may becomes confusing to use this notation mixed with interpolation.